# PKCS7 validation error: ASN1 corrupted data

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I am developing a java class that signs text files in PKCS7 format. I discovered that it is possible to do this using Sun libraries instead of BouncyCastle, and I developed the following method:

```
    public void AssinaPKCS7(String ArquivoAssinar) {

        String SrtResultPKCS7 = "";
        byte[] Conteudo;
        byte[] Hash;
        String DadosArq = "";
        String Linha = "";
        boolean AssinValid = false;

        try {
            FileInputStream Entrada = new FileInputStream(ArquivoAssinar);
            InputStreamReader Leitor = new InputStreamReader(Entrada, Charset);
            BufferedReader Buffer = new BufferedReader(Leitor);
            Linha = Buffer.readLine();

            while (Linha != null) {
                DadosArq = DadosArq + Linha;
                Linha = Buffer.readLine();
            }

            Buffer.close();

            Conteudo = DadosArq.getBytes(Charset);

            X500Name xName = X500Name.asX500Name(Certif.getSubjectX500Principal());
            BigInteger serial = Certif.getSerialNumber();
            AlgorithmId digestAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA_oid);
            AlgorithmId signAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSAEncryption_oid);

            MessageDigest MessDig = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
            Hash = MessDig.digest(Conteudo);

            PKCS9Attribute Atributo1 = new PKCS9Attribute(PKCS9Attribute.CONTENT_TYPE_OID, ContentInfo.DATA_OID);
            PKCS9Attribute Atributo2 = new PKCS9Attribute(PKCS9Attribute.MESSAGE_DIGEST_OID, Hash); 
            PKCS9Attributes ConjuntoAtrib = new PKCS9Attributes(new PKCS9Attribute[] {Atributo1, Atributo2}); 

            Signature Sign = Signature.getInstance(AlgoritmoAssinatura);
            Sign.initSign(PrivPass);
            Sign.update(Conteudo);
            ResultadoAssinatura = Sign.sign();

            Signature Verif = Signature.getInstance(AlgoritmoAssinatura);
            Verif.initVerify(Certif);
            Verif.update(Conteudo);
            AssinValid = Verif.verify(ResultadoAssinatura);

            if (AssinValid) {
                try {
                    SignerInfo sInfo = new SignerInfo(xName, serial, digestAlgorithmId, ConjuntoAtrib, signAlgorithmId, ResultadoAssinatura, null);

                    ContentInfo cInfo = new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DIGESTED_DATA_OID, new DerValue(DerValue.tag_OctetString, Conteudo));

                    PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new AlgorithmId[] { digestAlgorithmId }, cInfo, new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] { Certif }, new SignerInfo[] { sInfo });

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new DerOutputStream();
                    p7.encodeSignedData(bOut);
                    byte[] encoded = bOut.toByteArray();
                    SrtResultPKCS7 = Encoder.encode(encoded);

                    FileOutputStream Saida = new FileOutputStream(ArquivoAssinar);
                    OutputStreamWriter Escritor = new OutputStreamWriter(Saida, Charset);
                    BufferedWriter BuffWriter = new BufferedWriter(Escritor); 
                    //BuffWriter.write(SrtResultPKCS7);
                    BuffWriter.write(bOut.toString());
                    BuffWriter.close();
                }
                catch (Exception E) {
                    E.printStackTrace();        
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Assinatura inválida");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

When I tryed to validate the resulting file in online validator https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATBHE/assinadoc/ValidadorAssinaturas.app/valida.aspx I got this error message:

**ASN1 corrupted data**

I checked the signature, she is OK. I believe the error is in som data convertion while generating PKCS7 result.

Has anyone had this problem? And how can I validate the PCKS7 result in java code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you checked the signature, other than the meaningless check in your code which repeats the mistake(s), but it was of the wrong data and since you didn't show us `AlgoritmoAssinatura` maybe the wrong method as well. You also have several other errors. Rather than detail all of them, here is an example that produces a valid result, with the changes commented:

```
// use test data for example
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS"); ks.load(new FileInputStream (args[0]), args[1].toCharArray());
PrivateKey PrivKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey (args[2], args[1].toCharArray());
X509Certificate Certif = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(args[2]);
String Message = "test";
String ArquivoAssinar = args[3];
String Charset = "ASCII"; // no idea, see below

String SrtResultPKCS7 = "";
byte[] Conteudo = Message.getBytes(Charset);
byte[] Hash;
//String DadosArq = "";
//String Linha = "";
//boolean AssinValid = false;

try {
    // the name in SignerInfo is the _Issuer_ name NOT the Subject
    X500Name xName = X500Name.asX500Name(Certif.getIssuerX500Principal());
    BigInteger serial = Certif.getSerialNumber();
    AlgorithmId digestAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.SHA_oid);
    AlgorithmId signAlgorithmId = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.RSAEncryption_oid);

    MessageDigest MessDig = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    Hash = MessDig.digest(Conteudo);

    PKCS9Attribute Atributo1 = new PKCS9Attribute(PKCS9Attribute.CONTENT_TYPE_OID, ContentInfo.DATA_OID);
    PKCS9Attribute Atributo2 = new PKCS9Attribute(PKCS9Attribute.MESSAGE_DIGEST_OID, Hash); 
    PKCS9Attributes ConjuntoAtrib = new PKCS9Attributes(new PKCS9Attribute[] {Atributo1, Atributo2}); 

    // when using signedattrs, signature is of the encoded attrs 
    // (without the context-implicit tag used when embedded in SignerInfo)
    Signature Sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    Sign.initSign(PrivKey);
    Sign.update(ConjuntoAtrib.getDerEncoding());
    byte[] ResultadoAssinatura = Sign.sign();

    SignerInfo sInfo = new SignerInfo(xName, serial, digestAlgorithmId, ConjuntoAtrib, signAlgorithmId, ResultadoAssinatura, null);
    // contenttype inside signed-data is data not digested-data  
    ContentInfo cInfo = new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DATA_OID, new DerValue(DerValue.tag_OctetString, Conteudo));

    PKCS7 p7 = new PKCS7(new AlgorithmId[] { digestAlgorithmId }, cInfo, new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] { Certif }, new SignerInfo[] { sInfo });

    ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new DerOutputStream();
    p7.encodeSignedData(bOut);
    byte[] encoded = bOut.toByteArray();
    // Java doesn't define a class 'Encoder' so I assume this is base64
    SrtResultPKCS7 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encoded); // gone in 11!

    FileOutputStream Saida = new FileOutputStream(ArquivoAssinar);
    OutputStreamWriter Escritor = new OutputStreamWriter(Saida, Charset);
    BufferedWriter BuffWriter = new BufferedWriter(Escritor);
    // this was correct for base64 (although the buffering is wasted)
    BuffWriter.write(SrtResultPKCS7);
    // this was nonsense -- it decodes the DER bytes as if they were characters,
    // which they aren't, and then OSW re-encodes them to probably wrong bytes
    //BuffWriter.write(bOut.toString());
    BuffWriter.close();
    // alternatively could write DER/binary with a Stream (NOT a Writer)
}
catch (Exception E) {
    E.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's not clear to me what output format you -- or the site you link -- want. 
Using binary/DER is fairly common, but can't be cut&pasted and is harder to work with. Base64 of DER is rare but not unknown. If you or they want the standard PEM format, used by a lot of software, that is NOT merely base64 of DER; it is base64 of DER PLUS line breaks every 64 characters AND dash-BEGIN and dash-END lines added.

Also, SHA-1 has been broken for collision more than a year; see https://shattered.io and the numerous Qs on cryptography.SX and security.SX about this. Even before that it was prohibited for signatures by numerous authorities since 2014 or 2015, including NIST (for the US government) and CABforum (for public web certificates). I don't know anything about the data you are signing, but if it is in any way important or valuable, and you have the option to use a better hash in your signature(s), you should.

ADDED: also I asume you realize that `sun.*` classes are not documented, not guaranteed, and may stop working anytime Oracle feels like it.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085. Thank you very much for your comments. in fact I see that I've made several mistakes. But let me clarify some points you have raised: the AlgoritmoAssinatura is a constant whose value is "SHA1withRSA" - the partner company that created the interface demands use of SHA-1. About the output, they demand Base64. In my tests, I try to save the file without Base64 just for validate the PCKS format on an official website that has this functionality. Thank you again, I will implement the changes you described.

Comment: @dave_thompson_85, is it possible to validate the final result in java?